# All grizzly workers want to insert (SQL) First grizzly insert okay, second SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, hsqldb, grizzly

I hope I can explain it well, because my problem is very time dependent.

I have a client sending data to the server (java). On the server I have a RestServer waiting for input from the client.

When the client sends data to the server it sends this data several times, until it receives an "okay-response" from the server. 
Sadly, this "ok" from the server can take time, because when the server gets the data from the client he has to do many things (Insert into database, ...) before the client gets a response back.

But during the working time of the grizzly worker one on the server the client sends again the data to the server and the next grizzly worker (grizzly worker number 2 starts) on the server and tries ALSO to INSERT into the database.

This happens because grizzly worker one hasn`t finished to insert into the database before grizzly worker 2 started and checked if the data is already in the database. Grizzly worker two thinks "no the data is not inserted into the database therefore I am going to insert".

Hopefully my picture can show what I have tried to explain:
[multithreading problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN7Tu.jpg)

Both workers think they have to insert into the database although grizzly worker one is still trying to insert into DB.

How can I tell grizzly worker two that there is already a grizzly worker one trying to insert into the database?

Or how can I stop grizzly worker two for a second?
Or how can I solve this problem?

Only the code what you can see in the picture:

```
    public void setPunkteFuerTanz(Wertung eineWertung) 
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    int anzahlPunkteIDs;
    Integer runde = eineWertung.getRunde();
    if(runde == 0)
    {
        //something to do here
    }

    /*Jurorid 1 ist Admin, der darf mehrere Zeilen schreiben, deshalb 
     *anzahlPunkteIDs immer 0 */
    if(eineWertung.getJurorID() == 1)
    {
        anzahlPunkteIDs = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        anzahlPunkteIDs = Integer.valueOf(sqlFunctions.getResultFromCustomQuery(
            "select count(punkteid) from punkte "
            .concat("where jurorid=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getJurorID()))
            .concat(" and tid=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getTanzID()))
            .concat(" and runde=").concat(String.valueOf(runde))).toString());            
    }

    if(anzahlPunkteIDs == 1)
    {
        //Tanz schon bewertet
        sqlFunctions.setExecuteUpdate("UPDATE PUNKTE SET "
            .concat("choreo=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getChoreo()))
            .concat(",technik=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getTechnik()))
            .concat(",level=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getLevel()))
            .concat(",gesamt=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getGesamt()))
            .concat(",futuretalent=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getFutureTalent()))
            .concat(",bestchoreo=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getBestChoreo()))
            .concat(",bestcostume=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getBestCostume()))
            .concat(",runde=").concat(String.valueOf(runde))
            .concat(" where jurorid=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getJurorID()))
            .concat(" and tid=").concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getTanzID()))
            .concat(" and runde=").concat(String.valueOf(runde)));
    }
    else
    {
        //Tanz noch nicht bewertet
        int letztePunkteID;
        Object letztePunkteIDObject = 
                this.sqlFunctions.getResultFromCustomQuery("select punkteid from punkte");

        letztePunkteID = (letztePunkteIDObject == null) ? 
                0 : (Integer.valueOf(letztePunkteIDObject.toString())+1);

        this.sqlFunctions.setExecuteUpdate("insert into punkte "
            .concat("(punkteid,jurorid,choreo,technik,level,gesamt,")
            .concat("futuretalent,bestchoreo,bestcostume,runde,tid) ")
            .concat("values(").concat(String.valueOf(letztePunkteID)).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getJurorID())).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getChoreo())).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getTechnik())).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getLevel())).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getGesamt())).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getFutureTalent())).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getBestChoreo())).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getBestCostume())).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(runde)).concat(",")
            .concat(String.valueOf(eineWertung.getTanzID())).concat(")"));
```

//UPDATE
Because synchronize did not work I tried the hint with the merge-query.
Due to the fact that my my merge statement is too long for a comment I will update it here:
I think I have made it with a Merged query. Instead of the insert statement I have written this query:`

```
    MERGE INTO punkte pu USING
    (VALUES 1,2,3,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,5) temp (punkteid, tid,jurorid,runde,choreo,technik,level,gesamt,futuretalent,bestchoreo,bestcostume) 
    ON temp.punkteid = pu.punkteid
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
    pu.punkteid=temp.punkteid,pu.tid = temp.tid,pu.jurorid=temp.jurorid,pu.runde=temp.runde,pu.choreo=temp.choreo,pu.technik=temp.technik,pu.level=temp.level,pu.gesamt=temp.gesamt,pu.futuretalent=temp.futuretalent,pu.bestchoreo=temp.bestchoreo,pu.bestcostume=temp.bestcostume
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (punkteid, tid,jurorid,runde,choreo,technik,level,gesamt,futuretalent,bestchoreo,bestcostume)  VALUES (temp.punkteid, temp.tid,temp.jurorid,temp.runde,temp.choreo,temp.technik,temp.level,temp.gesamt,temp.futuretalent,temp.bestchoreo,temp.bestcostume)`
```

//UPDATE 2

Yes, thanks all for your efforts it is working with "merged" like a charm.

Also a very bigh thanks to Koos Gadellaa for his patience, going with me through other possible solutions

Comment: You should perform an "upsert" operation using hsqldb's Merge. When the row does not exist it inserts. When it exists it updates. http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement

Comment: You must use a MERGE statement as the first comment suggests. This will let the database engine handle the different situations with a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own transactions. Have a database field, get a lock on it, ensure that you have the lock on it, and then do your stuff.

Looking at your (added) code example, it would probably be something like:

```
public void setPunkteFuerTanz(Wertung einWertung) {
    try{
        this.sqlFunctions.setExecuteUpdate("select * from LOCKTABLE for update");
        // if we get here, we have a mutex
        // all your original code then goes here

    } catch(SomeExceptionWhichOccursWhenLockingTimesOut e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Another option would be to synchronize on a static block. As long as the two threads run in the same JVM, you can probably use a `synchronized(Object.class) { ... }` around your function, which should lock as well.

Comment: How can this help me?
I have found this article explaining transaction:
http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/

Its great if I have several sql statements behind and one fails that I can easily rollback.

But I think I have another situation: I have two workers doing the same thing (insert into). How does transaction help me if both try to insert?

Also if the transaction 1 would block another transaction, as soon as transaction one is finsished, worker two (transaction two) would still try to insert into the database.

Comment: Worker two will try to insert it, but it will *know* it is there. As if it happened yesterday, instead of only a few microseconds before. But it will be guaranteed that there is nobody else messing around with the database. If your program currently doesn't support that, it should start doing that too (but I gather, it probably does)

Comment: You do not mark your desired insertion for update, but something unrelated entirely, created for this purpose. This acquires a lock.
Essentially, you're creating a special token which you need to have to start. Consider going shopping(executing your current code), this is saying that you need to have a valid parking ticket to enter the mall, and there is only one parking place. So the first one to park gets the ticket and can shop. The rest has to wait, until you leave, and then someone else can park, and shop. Anybody leaving is guaranteed to have finished shopping not disturbed by others

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Very hard to understand for me :-/

1. I have tried to synchronize the function, as you wrote in your first reply
I tried now the program several times and I didn not get any errors anymore. The only change I made:
`public synchronized void setPunkteFuerTanz(Wertung eineWertung) 
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    { `
Little bit afraid if this small change will work as expected.

2. As @Devon_C_Miller said there is also the possiblity to use "upset". Sadly did not understood it in the documentation :-/

Comment: Okay synchronized is not working as expected.
I do not get any Exceptions anymore, but now I have two exact entries in my database.

Comment: That is easy to check for, right? I'm not sure how your client works, but hey, it just might mean that a packet gets lost and is delivered after 10 minutes. Similar situation, your application should support that. So, in the synchronized block, check for it, and handle appropriately.

Comment: It`s not easy to check for :-D
My brain says all the time two same entries in the database is unpossible! But I have two exact same entries in the database.

Synchronized means for me that workers enter this function one after the other. That would mean that it is unpossible two have two workers inserting the same data.

Is it possible to write these two sql queries "update" and "insert" into "upset"-queries?

Comment: Are the workers in different JVM's? or are they in separate threads? If in different JVM's, synchronized won't do and you'll have to use a database lock.

Comment: I appreciate your patience, unfortunately I have to say with this code '    public void setPunkteFuerTanz(Wertung eineWertung) 
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException { synchronized(Object.class)'
no worker is going into this function. And this is a RestfulWebService and how I understand this service is that every worker is in his own thread. One JVM.
https://grizzly.java.net/dependencies.html - RestfullWebService Grizzly Workers

Comment: Strange. was it an admin? Admins can add the same punkte multiple times.
Can you verify your failed result?

Comment: Checked, if the client sends crap, but the data is fine. It is not an admin.
Next thing is I meant that no worker is going into the whole function
No one reaches:
int anzahlPunkteIDs;
    ...

Comment: Just read up on `synchronized`. It is synchronized _per instance_. If there are multiple instances of the object, multiple threads can execute them. What is desired is that only one thread can execute, even if there are multiple instances. What you need is a static monitor object, so instead of `synchronized` you need `synchronized(Object.class)`. This can only be used in a synchronized block, so you'll need to modify your function. Instead of `public synchronized method(...) { ... }` you'll need to write it as `public method(...){ synchronized(Object.class) { ... } }`